# Test fails with `flutter test` but passes when debugged from test file

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, testing, dart

How can I read a file using a relative path when running `flutter test`?

When running `flutter test` the `File('path/to/file')` needs an absolute path but a relative path works when debugging.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Using VS Code, I can run a test by starting debug while in one of the test files. By doing so, the test will pass when using a relative path to read a file. However, when I run `flutter test` from the terminal, the same test fails because it is unable to find the file unless I change it to use an absolute path in which case the test will pass.

This is the line of code in the test that tries to create a model from the json file:

```
final tUserModel = UserModel.fromJson(json.decode(fixture('user_cached.json')));
```

The `fixture` function is imported from a different file and implemented as follows:

```
import 'dart:io';
String fixture(String name) => File('test/fixtures/$name').readAsStringSync();
```

When using that relative path I get the following output from terminal:

```
flutter test
00:03 +3 ~1 -1: loading /home/user/MyApp/test/features/user/data/datasources/user_local_data_source_test.dart [E]                                                                                       
Failed to load "/home/user/MyApp/test/features/user/data/datasources/user_local_data_source_test.dart": Cannot open file, path = 'test/fixtures/user_cached.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
dart:io                                                                     _File.readAsStringSync
fixtures/fixture_reader.dart 3:60                                           fixture
features/user/data/datasources/user_local_data_source_test.dart 27:40       main.<fn>
package:test_api                                                            Declarer.group
package:flutter_test/src/test_compat.dart 226:13                            group
features/user/data/datasources/user_local_data_source_test.dart 25:3        main
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
package:test_api                                                            RemoteListener.start
/tmp/flutter_tools.DRSZQD/flutter_test_listener.IPDUJJ/listener.dart 16:25  serializeSuite
/tmp/flutter_tools.DRSZQD/flutter_test_listener.IPDUJJ/listener.dart 43:36  main
```

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.19.0-4.1.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

- How can I get `flutter test` to work with a relative file path?
- Is there another way to run **all** tests from VS Code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
String fixture(String name) {
  var dir = Directory.current.path;
  if (dir.endsWith('/test')) {
    dir = dir.replaceAll('/test', '');
  }
  return File('$dir/test/fixtures/$name').readAsStringSync();
}
```

The issue has been raised a few times here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20907

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

String fixture(String name) {
  final testDirectory = join(
    Directory.current.path,
    Directory.current.path.endsWith('test') ? '' : 'test',
  );
  return File('$testDirectory/fixtures/$name').readAsStringSync();
}
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20907#issuecomment-466185328